# What is N'@date referring to?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anybody please help me to identify what the `N'@date` is referring to between the two set measures in the following exec statement?

```
declare @sql nvarchar(4000), @dt datetime;

set @dt = '2015-10-01';

set @sql = N'select * from dim_person

where person_sid
in
(
select max(person_sid)  from dim_person

where [Effective_To] <= @date

group by person_id_number
)';

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@date datetime',@dt;
```

Comment: As you are new here (Btw: Welcome!) please allow me one hint: It is very kind of you to say Thank you, but it would be even kinder, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Comment: @Shnugo, but how would someone know the 'best' to his question. If she/he could make the distinction, then probably she/he would know the answer in the first place :) In other words, it only marks the case is solved for the OP her/himself (even the marked one might be the worst choice).

Comment: @CetinBasoz yes, this is personal opinion... It happens that users accept an answer where I'd say it is not the best or even wrong... That's SO... If there are more *good* answers the question giver must decide for one. Anyway better than not to mark one and let it *unsolved*... Don't you think so? On the long run it will be fair for all...

Comment: @Shnugo, right, it just means 'thank you'. For example in this case, he didn't ask the first N'...' but the one that is parameter to sp_executesql. In that regard, I would think the answer was Mincong Huang's reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN - sp_executesql (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx), the syntax for `sp_executesql` is:

```
sp_executesql [ @stmt = ] statement  
[   
  { , [ @params = ] N'@parameter_name data_type [ OUT | OUTPUT ][ ,...n ]' }   
     { , [ @param1 = ] 'value1' [ ,...n ] }  
]
```

In your case,

1. `@sql` refers to your SQL statement
2. `N'@date datetime'` refers to the 1st parameter name and its data type `datetime`
3. `@dt` is the value for the 1st parameter

Answer (score 2):

It is not just N'@date, it is N'@date datetime' and it is passing @date variable declaration parameter to sp_executesql as an nvarchar value.

PS: Apart from what it is doing there, that SQL statements are in general useless and prone to error. Normally you wouldn't even want to use sp_executesql for this. If you have to using a Datetime string like that is prone to error. At least it should be '20151001'. That dashed format doesn't work under all versions and language settings.

Comment: For some examples, see the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Comment: @Andomar, why do I need to see MSDN doc for some examples?

Answer (score 2):

`sp_executesql` expects the input parameter in unicode string. Therefore you have to pass in a `NVARCHAR(x)`-string

```
SELECT 'hello'  --creates the string "hello" as VARCHAR

SELECT N'hello' --create the string "hello" as unicode string (NVARCHAR)
```

in your line

```
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@date datetime',@dt;
```

... the `N'@date datetime'` is one single input parameter.

Here you can read more about [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)